# Modelo de datos Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Buenas,

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
    "tempext": [
        {
            "attrName": "tempext",
            "attrValue": "17.054.495",
            "recvTime": "2017-11-26T18:45:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "tempext",
            "attrValue": "17.054.495",
            "recvTime": "2017-11-26T18:45:00.000Z"
        }
 ],
    "tempint": [
        {
            "attrName": "tempint",
            "attrValue": "19.018.230",
            "recvTime": "2017-11-26T18:45:00.000Z"
        },

        {
            "attrName": "tempint",
            "attrValue": "28.634.987",
            "recvTime": "2017-10-24T12:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Estoy tratando de trabajar con el en Angular 2 pero no tengo claro como poner la información del tempint o tempext en el modelo de datos.

Todo lo que he diseñado es mas básico y en el modelo de datos no se tiene que hacer referencia a esos dos objetos es algo mas simple.

```
export class Temp{
  constructor(
    public recvTime: string,
    public attrName: string,
    public attrValue: string
  ){}
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.

**EDIT01**

Estoy intentando utilizar la interfaz

```
interface MyData {
tempext: MyElem[];
tempint: MyElem[];
}

interface MyElem {
recvTime: string;
attrName: string;
attrValue: string;
}
```

pero a la hora de asignar a mi controller la interfaz no tengo claro como hacerlo.

Antes de tener los dos objetos y con la clase lo hacia de la siguiente forma:
public mostrarfechaline(){

```
this._invService.getinvfechasensores(this.fecha3,this.fecha4).subscribe(
                  response => {
                  if (!response) {
                    console.log('error al cargar datos');
                  } else {
this.temp = response;
```

y así recuperaba todos los valores del campo:

```
var f0=this.temp.map(tempext => tempext.recvTime);
```

Como puedo hacer esto ahora?

así recupero el JSON completo del get en el servicio:

```
getinvfecha(fecha1,fecha2){

    return this._http.get(this.url+'getinvfecha/'+fecha1+'/'+fecha2).map(res => res.json());

  }
```

Comment: Usa interface en lugar de clase

Comment: Hola, si me gustaría saber como definir esa clase o esa interface

Comment: En tu `getInvFecha()` utiliza  `.map(res => <Temp[]>res.json()`. Lo has probado?. Luego en tu `this.temp = response;`, ya tendrías un arreglo (`Temp[]`) con `TempItem[]` en el interior de cada elemento.

Comment: Buenas, Acabo de cambiar el  método getInvFecha por que me has puesto, ahora solo me falta lo ultimo que me has comentado, como puedo ver mi array tempext y tempint @FedericoMadoery

Comment: Cuando recorro la response: for( let i in response){
                          console.log('console log: ' + i)
                        }
me devuelce console log: tempext console log: tempint No consigo acceder a los objetos

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente definir los atributos de una variable cuyo valor obtienes con JSON.parse() y no vas a usar realmente el constructor de la clase, te recomiendo usar interfaces, que simplemente indican cómo es el objeto:

```
interface MyData {
  tempext: MyElem[];
  tempint: MyElem[];
}

interface MyElem {
  recvTime: string;
  attrName: string;
  attrValue: string;
}
```

Y cuando obtengas el valor hagas simplemente algo como:

```
 let data= JSON.parse(response) as MyData;
```

Comment: he editado el post por si puedes ayudarme. gracias

Comment: Buenas, he probado lo que has comentado y me da el siguiente error:
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Seguramente no tengas que hacer JSON.parse(response) porque ya tienes el objeto en lugar de un string, simplemente asigna el valor

Answer (score 0):

La definición de **Clase** esta bien es así:

```
export class Temp{
  constructor(tempext: TempItem[])
  ){}
  constructor(tempint: TempItem[])
  ){}
}
export class TempItem{
  constructor(
    recvTime: string,
    attrName: string,
    attrValue: string
  ){}
}
```

Si quieres usar una **interface**, debería ser así:

```
interface Temp{
    tempext: TempItem[];
    tempint: TempItem[];
}
export interface TempItem{
    recvTime: string;
    attrName: string;
    attrValue: string;
}
```

Luego para convertir tu JSON tienes una opción para cada una:

**Interface:**

```
 this.http.get('...')
     .map(res => <Temp[]>res.json());
```

**Clase:**

```
this.http.get('...')
    .map(res => {
      let data = res.json();
      return data.map(d => {
        return new Temp(d);
      });
    });
```

### Diferencia:

> Las interfaces solo están en tiempo de compilación. Esto solo le
> permite verificar que los datos esperados, recibidos sigan una
> estructura particular. Para esto, puedes enviar tu contenido a esta
> interfaz.
>
> En cambio la clase está presente en el tiempo de ejecución ( como la
> función de constructor) y puede definir mas métodos en ellas con el
> procesamiento si fuese necesario.

Comment: he editado el post por si puedes ayudarme. gracias

Comment: Buenas, Acabo de cambiar el método getInvFecha por que me has puesto, ahora solo me falta lo ultimo que me has comentado, como puedo ver mi array tempext y tempint @FedericoMadoery